# What would be the cause of this worker process crash?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

We experienced a worker process crash in our ASP.NET 2.0 application.

Here is the report that was dumped when the worker process crashed:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=129575741278397484
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=7c124dac-c466-11e0-a346-68b599c966f4
WOW64=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=w3wp.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=7.5.7600.16385
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=4a5bcd2b
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=6.1.7600.16823
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=4de7264e
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=e053534f
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0000b9bc
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
UI[2]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\pcwum.DLL
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\IISUTIL.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wphost.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\nativerd.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\XmlLite.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\ktmw32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\IISRES.DLL
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5\MSVCR80.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\iiscore.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\W3TP.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3dt.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\HTTPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\syswow64\Normaliz.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\system32\faultrep.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\dirlist.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\static.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\modrqflt.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\custerr.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\loghttp.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisreqs.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\isapi.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\filter.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\webengine.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisetw.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iisfreb.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\redirect.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authcert.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlauthz.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authbas.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmd5.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authmap.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iprestr.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\logcust.dll
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\wbhst_pm.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\syswow64\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\23bc3936180ff789f44259a211dfc7fc\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System\bb2b3b9c7c2941a3f485940d59a68131\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web\d2d39614c7251ce46674ecc4516e9e85\System.Web.ni.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\system32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Configuration\4c57c8b1594281c44d9f04a3b3d76131\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Xml\447fd8040376beceb8f2572214434843\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\system32\version.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.JScript\c1d036e7d21aa16c6ecd5903f1380245\Microsoft.JScript.ni.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.ServiceModel\fe0eb1e786dd2cb1af265642f98987df\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Core\800db9c1d9899d341145e2610d0fdec9\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web.Abstract#\6c76cacd8bb7624ae8cc37da12b20c31\System.Web.Abstractions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web.Extensio#\9e14cbd9cedcd676a5846b7bb3f00578\System.Web.Extensions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.Web\2.112.1.2__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.Web.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\SMDiagnostics\b2de5b6831274468b42d17ab83649810\SMDiagnostics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web.Services\c19548b56ec8119d2f41e057548a8e19\System.Web.Services.ni.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\assembly\dl3\1ef7f3cf\398c7100_ed58ca01\SonarEngine.DLL
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Data\179b93bc916180c4648a44b6fd79a1de\System.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\assembly\dl3\cf1595f1\a896187d_e657ca01\clsEchoEngine.DLL
LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\assembly\dl3\48523473\64b3c57e_e657ca01\EchoEnginePool.DLL
LoadedModule[122]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\assembly\dl3\022778b1\aaa284e5_992aca01\EpsiXml.DLL
LoadedModule[123]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.1.2__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\1c9d526783dc991a4c0db0adde215f77\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.EnterpriseSe#\57d7078bc796f91103e92b210de3c3d6\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[126]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[127]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
LoadedModule[128]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Data.SqlXml\e121c1e73fabfce6f229546388585865\System.Data.SqlXml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[129]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualBas#\4e3e6b682ceb418593e5964993baf846\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[130]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Transactions\33eef8d1899573df9ab38acc0ffff07a\System.Transactions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[131]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
LoadedModule[132]=D:\app\inetAdmin\product\11.2.0\client_1\OCI.DLL
LoadedModule[133]=D:\app\inetAdmin\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\OraOps11w.dll
LoadedModule[134]=D:\app\inetAdmin\product\11.2.0\client_1\OraOCIEI11.dll
LoadedModule[135]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[136]=C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
LoadedModule[137]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.Vsa\b933f490039e14eb2e4be2e597ae07ed\Microsoft.Vsa.ni.dll
LoadedModule[138]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorpe.dll
LoadedModule[139]=C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
LoadedModule[140]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.EnterpriseSe#\57d7078bc796f91103e92b210de3c3d6\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[141]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[142]=C:\Windows\system32\Com\comadmin.dll
LoadedModule[143]=C:\Windows\system32\MfcSubs.dll
LoadedModule[144]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7600.16385_none_72fc7cbf861225ca\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[145]=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[146]=C:\Windows\system32\windowscodecsext.dll
LoadedModule[147]=C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
LoadedModule[148]=C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
LoadedModule[149]=C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
LoadedModule[150]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\diasymreader.dll
LoadedModule[151]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\assembly\dl3\295de4c1\4c9fc2e5_992aca01\EchoMQ.DLL
LoadedModule[152]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\assembly\dl3\6bdf2035\b19152e5_992aca01\RegistryAccessDLL.DLL
LoadedModule[153]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Messaging\59069ccdbc65fce202bb976999326efa\System.Messaging.ni.dll
LoadedModule[154]=C:\Windows\system32\mqrt.dll
LoadedModule[155]=C:\Windows\system32\mqsec.dll
LoadedModule[156]=C:\Windows\system32\LOGONCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[157]=C:\Windows\system32\SAMCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[158]=C:\Windows\system32\DSROLE.DLL
LoadedModule[159]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\webservices_echoengine\4740617c\23f17d74\App_Web_defaultwsdlhelpgenerator.aspx.cdcab7d2.cvuegqau.dll
LoadedModule[160]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web.Mobile\7967455a68fba1ebdccdcc88a49c7f11\System.Web.Mobile.ni.dll
LoadedModule[161]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web.RegularE#\32f0e82ec89a541cd35b1199026bdc79\System.Web.RegularExpressions.ni.dll
FriendlyEventName=APPCRASH
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=IIS Worker Process
AppPath=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
ReportDescription=Stopped working
```

This occurred on our server running Windows 2008 R2 64 bit.

What caused this error and how do I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 7):

The clue to this problem is in the Exception Code:

```
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=e053534f      <====== this is the clue
```

This exception code indicates that there was a "soft stack overflow" raised by the CLR. Please see the commentary at the end of this MSDN Library article:

> [StackOverflowException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

What you'll need to do is install the [Debug Diagnostic Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798) and configure it to dump your worker process whenever this crash happens.

Once you've captured a dump of the process you'll need to load this into WinDBG and use SOS
to narrow down the root cause.

There are several great articles on how to analyse a worker process crash dump:

> [.NET Debugging Demos - Information and setup instructions - Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)
>
> [Diagnosing Tricky ASP.Net Production Issues with DebugDiag and winDbg](http://martinondotnet.blogspot.com/search/label/e053534f)
>
> [System.StackOverflowException with IronPython 2.6.0 and 2.6.1](http://www.bnsstevenson.com/blog/?p=41#more-41)

The articles by Tess Ferrandez are great and I learned to master WinDBG and SOS from her labs.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Kev's excellent answer -

1. Right Click  > My Computer > Properties > Advanced Tab > click the Settings button under Start up and Recovery > choose "Complete Memory Dump" and specify a location with enough HDD space equal to the amount of RAM in the server.
2. Once the crash has reoccurred and the memory dump is successful. Install WinDBG, open up WinDBG,  File > Open > load the memory dump (.dmp)
3. Then load SOS (eg .loadby sos mscorwks)
4. !clrstack

This will churn out a huge stack trace that will most likely identify a recursive function or some huge allocation as Brian Grunkemeyer - MSFT said in the link Kev provided.

Your probably going to have to put a limit on the depth of the recursive calls... or something similar.

Good luck! You can always call Microsoft PSS if you need help with the diagnosis. Remember to download the Public Symbols from Microsoft before you issue !analyze and !clrstack - in order to see method names. If you need to see method bodies in Microsoft DLLs in a dump file you need the private symbols (only avail to Microsoft engineers).

Comment: Step 1 applies only to kernel dumps, not user mode dumps. Instead set up [WER LocalDumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)