# VB.NET SplashScreen "Program stopped working"

Tags: vb.net, windows-7-x64, crash

Environment:

- Visual Basic (version 2008)
- .NET Framework 3.5
- Windows 7 64 bits

Problem:

I have a program with the next start code, that during years worked.

```
Public Class SplashFrm

Private WithEvents DoSomeWork As ValidateCls
Private Sub SplashFrm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.Show()      
    DoSomeWork = New ValidateCls
    Application.DoEvents()  
    DoSomeWork.doWorks()
End Sub
Private Sub React() Handles DoSomeWork.WorkFinished
    LoginFrm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class


Public Class ValidateCls
    Public Event WorkFinished()

 Sub doWorks()
        AddHandler System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf OnUnhandledException
        Try
            'here code to validate licenses. 
         'i can not put the code, but it works fine because I can see that is validating ok.
        Catch ex As Exception
            SaveError("ValidateCls-1", ex.ToString)
            End
        End Try
        RaiseEvent WorkFinished()
    End Sub

Private Sub OnUnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Try
        HandleUnhandledException(e.ExceptionObject)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub HandleUnhandledException(ByVal o As Object)
    If o Is Nothing Then Return
    Try
        Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(o, Exception)
        MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace, "Unhandled exception.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unhandled exception.")
    Finally
        Application.Exit()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

But the last week, in some computers with Windows 7 64 bits, sudddenly crashes: "program stopped working":

> DEscription: Stopped working
>
> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>
> Application Name: nameApp.exe
>
> Application Version:    1.0.5116
>
> Application Timestamp:  52c6d693
>
> Fault Module Name:  KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.18229
>
> Fault Module Timestamp: 51fb1116
>
> Exception Code: e053534f
>
> Exception Offset:   0000c41f

the code inside "Sub doWorks()" working properly because I checked that validates the license. The error is inside or after:   RaiseEvent WorkFinished(), because LoginForm is not showed.

What is wrong?

Comment: What does the exception say? Look at the stacktrace of the exception that was throwen.

Comment: no throw any message from the application and the error is not catched in the program. Only is displayed this message from Windows

Comment: Looking for the Exception Code, one of the first hits leads me [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7034131/578843) and [**here**](http://blog.fogcreek.com/production-debugging-a-story-about-exception-code-0xe053534f/). You'll have to do some more digging yourself though.